# How to remove duplicate rows and update relationships in mysql 8

Tags: mysql

I read many posts that teach how to remove duplicate row. But in my situation, there is relationship between tables. I would like to update the relationship before deleting the duplicate rows.

I also read a question in 2013 that is very similar to my situation but I didn't archive it using the method in the posts.
[deleting duplicates in sql and modifying relationship table accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009190/deleting-duplicates-in-sql-and-modifying-relationship-table-accordingly)

I am new to mysql and need some help. Thank you in advance. I build this with laravel 8 and mysql 8 and I manage the tables in phpmyadmin.

Here is my tables:

```
actors
id       actor_id
1        fghj
2        fghj        (to be removed)
3        fghj        (to be removed)
4        zxcv
5        zxcv        (to be removed)

videos
id       code
1        aaa
2        bbb
3        ccc

actor_video
actor_id()     video_id
(=actors.id)   (=videos.id)
1            1
1            3        (to be modified to 1 1)
2            4
2            5        (to be modified to 2 4)
3            2        (to be modified to 3 1)
3            3        (to be modified to 3 1)
```

I have an idea but I failed to code it. My plan is:

1. create a column in actors `correct_id`
2. find all duplicate rows in actors with `COUNT(actor_id)`
3. assign `correct_id = min(id)` in each duplicate group
4. modify the relationship table by replacing `actor_video.actor_id` to `actors.correct_id`
5. remove duplicate rows in actor_video
6. remove duplicate rows in actors

```
Step 1:
ALTER TABLE actors
ADD correct_id varchar(255);
```

```
Step2:
SELECT actor_id,COUNT(actor_id)
FROM `actors` 
GROUP BY actor_id
HAVING COUNT(actor_id) >1
```

```
Step3:
????
(this is wrong code. Just try to express my idea)
UPDATE actors
SET correct_id = min(id)
WHERE COUNT(actor_id) >1
```

Then I stuck since step 3. Sorry if this a slow and stupid idea. Please correct me for a efficient way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the minimal id

You can use this update method to directly change the ids from the bridge table, with the correct id.

and here is a canonical answer how to [remove dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE actors (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `actor_id` VARCHAR(4),
>   `correct_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO actors
>   (`id`, `actor_id`, `correct_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'fghj', '0'),
>   ('2', 'fghj', '0'),
>   ('3', 'fghj', '0'),
>   ('4', 'zxcv', '0'),
>   ('5', 'zxcv', '0');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT actor_id,MIN(id)
> FROM `actors` 
> GROUP BY actor_id
> ```

> ```
> actor_id | MIN(id)
> :------- | ------:
> fghj     |       1
> zxcv     |       4
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE 
> actors a1 INNER JOIN (SELECT actor_id,MIN(id) minid
> FROM `actors` 
> GROUP BY actor_id) a2 USING (actor_id)
> SET correct_id = minid
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM actors
> ```
>
> ```
> id | actor_id | correct_id
> -: | :------- | ---------:
>  1 | fghj     |          1
>  2 | fghj     |          1
>  3 | fghj     |          1
>  4 | zxcv     |          4
>  5 | zxcv     |          4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=113a2851eeed4fa6ea3393fae8c8963c)*

Comment: Thank you guys. I tried both methods from Akina and nbk. Both methods works fine for my condition. I will choose this as the best answer as it seems more fit to the question. I would like to emphasize again that both answers worked very well!

Comment: upvote the other answer, if it was helpful too

Answer (score 1):

Update junction table

```
UPDATE actor_video av
JOIN actors a1 ON a1.id = av.actor_id
JOIN ( SELECT MIN(id) id, actor_id
       FROM actors
       GROUP BY actor_id ) a2 ON a1.actor_id = a2.actor_id
SET av.actor_id = a2.id;
```

then delete excess rows

```
DELETE a1
FROM actors a1
JOIN actors a2 ON a1.actor_id = a2.actor_id
WHERE a1.id > a2.id;
```

Or use more safe deletion:

```
DELETE
FROM actors
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM actor_video 
                   WHERE actors.id = actor_video .actor_id );
```

Comment: Thank you Akina. The query works very well. And also, it doesn't require us to create an additional column "correct_id". Really learn the mechanism how to update a table corresponding to values in another table. All I need to do next is to remove the duplicate relationship. Thank you again!